# Recoger VM arguments desde Angular 9 [ variables de ambiente ]

Tags: java, angular, tomcat

Tengo una aplicación Angular de frontend con Java en Backend y Tomcat como servidor.
Bien, pues necesito poder recoger las variables de entorno definidas en Tomcat, las cuales especifican el entorno en el que se va a trabajar, para poder realizar las peticiones correspondientes desde Angular a Java.

No puedo definir los entornos en environment.ts ni enviarlas desde Java a Angular.
Necesito recogerlas directamente desde Angular al igual que lo puede hacer java con System.getProperties();

¿Alguien puede ayudarme?
Gracias.

Comment: Eso no se puede. Angular se ejecuta en el navegador.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edición 2022-01-21

Es factible y 100 porciento seguro. Actualmente lo utilizo en producción. El fichero a modificar que leerá angular se carga dinámicamente en el servidor. Lo único a tomar en cuenta que no debe exponer datos sensibles como contraseñas.

## Se puede realizar, pero tienes que complicar el flujo de trabajo.

Voy a listar los pasos que he tratado de recrear con una misma intención pero en un servidor de nodejs de manera muy general.

1. Se requiere crear un archivo de script que angular lea y agregue a los archivos del build.
2. Compilar angular.
3. El contenido de la carpeta build se debe servir como contenido estático para que pueda ser accessible ( obviando que esto debe ser desde el servidor del cual quieres obtener las variables de ambiente )
4. Tu servidor, al arrancar, debe de modificar la estructura del archivo previamente asignado a angular. Por defecto angular confiara en este fichero.

### Contras

- Puedes generar errores graves si no defines bien las variables.
- Requiere mucha más lógica en angular
- Problemas de seguridad desconocidos

### Pros

- No lo he usado en producción, sorry...

Puedes leer más acerca de esto en [este post](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/)